# How to notify the alertview before showing to any view or window?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a application for iPhone.I have done some simple animation with  start and stop buttons.I have a scenario to  got any alert (ex: reminder) i need to stop the animation with out clicking stop button.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with " stop the animation with out clicking stop button"?

Comment: For Example: Take wiggling effect in iPhone. when we hold the icon for some time, it will starts the animation.During the animation if i get any alert, i have to stop that animation with out clicking home button.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAlertViewDelegate) protocol.

And implement the method `- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView`. There you can stop the animation. And you can continue the animation once the alertview is dismissed which can be detected by using `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method.

Comment: Here the alertview delegate is nil and that too comes from different nsobject.